# Make EditText work on an activity start

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I'm trying to do some in app billing to remove ads.

I have this bit of code :

```
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
            Inventory inventory) {

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mAbHelper == null)
            return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
        mIsPremium = premiumPurchase != null;
        updateInterface();
    }
};

/**
 * Updates interface
 */
private void updateInterface() {
    Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btUpgrade);
    Button btUpgrade = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btUpgrade);
    if (mIsPremium) {
        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAntiAdsKey);

        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveAntiAdsKey);

        if (edittext != null && edittext.getText() != null) {
            Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE = edittext.getText().toString().trim();
        } else {
            Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE = "ERROR";
        }
        if ("".equals(Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE)
                || Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE.equals(this
                        .getString(R.string.app_name))) {
            Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE = "";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " ("
                            + edittext.getText() + ")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.ANTI_ADS_KEY, Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE);
        editor.commit();
        editor.clear();



    } else {
        btUpgrade.setEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

The thing is I have to press a button to make this code works.
I would like that this code works on an activity start.

I'm a newbie, so i'm wondering if it is possible ?

Thanks

Comment: No. Its not possible. In `onCreate`, just views are created, the values you enter will not be available then.

Comment: Is it possible when i click a button to do 2 different things?

Comment: i've edited the code to show you what i really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

put you code directly after you initialize your editbox. but if you want to keep it on button click and still want to execute on start up then you can do write `

```
saveButton.performClick()
```

after your savebutton OnClickListener code block. Also put it inside activity's onResume() method block so even if you activity starts from pause it will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to  press a button & want to make this code work on Activity start the remove the `onClickListener` of the button. Use this :

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAntiAdsKey);

saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveAntiAdsKey);

        if (edittext != null && edittext.getText() != null) {
            Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE = edittext.getText().toString()
                    .trim();
        } else {
            Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE = "ERROR";
        }
        if ("".equals(Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE)
                || Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE.equals(activity
                        .getString(R.string.app_name))) {
            Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE = "";
            Toast.makeText(PromoCode.this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    PromoCode.this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " ("
                            + edittext.getText() + ")",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.ANTI_ADS_KEY,
                Constants.ANTI_ADS_VALUE);
        editor.commit();
        editor.clear();
```

Comment: do you want that this code should execute on every word you type?

Comment: Actually i don't want to type a word. i want that when a user buys an item via the in-app billing. when the user consumes the item the app should send a code to the Constants so that the features would unlock.